# (Qt) Create signal from QButtonGroup of PushButtons?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I am so confused on how this whole thing works.

I have some pushbuttons that I put into a group like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    AddSlotsToGroup();
}

void MainWindow::AddSlotsToGroup()
{
    QButtonGroup* group = new QButtonGroup(this);
    group->addButton(ui->slot_0);
    group->addButton(ui->slot_1);
    //...
}
```

And I want to create a slot that gets the id of the button that was clicked in that group. (Sorry if I explained that poorly :( )

So this is what I did (pure guess after googling)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    AddSlotsToGroup();
    connect(QPushButton* group, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), this, SLOT(onGroupButtonClicked(int)));
}

void MainWindow::onGroupButtonClicked(int id)
{
    qDebug() << id;
}
```

And to no surprise, I got an error saying group is an undeclared identifier and that QPushButton was an illegal use etc.

I hate to say that I have only used signals/slots from the designer window, so I really just need this one thing, and then I'm set for the future. :)

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    AddSlotsToGroup();
}

void MainWindow::AddSlotsToGroup()
{
    QButtonGroup* group = new QButtonGroup(this);
    group->addButton(ui->slot_0);
    group->addButton(ui->slot_1);
    //...
    connect(group, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)),
            this, SLOT(onGroupButtonClicked(int)));
}
```

By the way, you need to learn C++ first to master Qt.

Comment: This worked perfectly :) I can't thank you enough! One quick question though. In my slot, 

"void MainWindow::onGroupButtonClicked(int id)"

I did this 

"qDebug() << id;"

and my output is alway a negative number... Why is this?

Comment: Concerning documentation for addButton... "Automatically assigned ids are guaranteed to be negative, starting with -2. If you are also assigning your own ids, use positive values to avoid conflicts." ...these ids are always negative.

Comment: Thanks you :)  I will look into adding id's as I'm adding the buttons

Answer (score 2):

First you need to include QButtonGroup.

```
#include <QButtonGroup>
```

Your connection is malformed, please save "group" pointer as class member first and then use following:

```
connect(group, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), this, SLOT(onGroupButtonClicked(int)));
```

Comment: Yes I already added that include statement. I've never learned what a class is yet as I'm still learning c++. Thanks for your answer :)